# execute multiple command for update vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, insert-update

i am working on a vb project . in this i need to save some record to one table and update some records in another table in one event or click .. i am doing like this .

```
dim simpan as new sqlcommand
conn = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
conn.Open()
simpan = New SqlCommand()
simpan.Connection = conn
simpan.CommandType = CommandType.Text
simpan.CommandText = "update barang set (nama_barang,harga)values(" & TextBox3.Text & ",'" & TextBox4.Text & "') where kode_barang = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
simpan.ExecuteNonQuery()
tampil()
MsgBox("Data Berhasil Diubah", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Informasi")
conn.Close()
```

but it giving error as "incorrect syntax near '('" .. i am not getting where i go wrong .. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use update like this, change your code like so:

```
 simpan.CommandText = "update barang set nama_barang = '" & TextBox3.Text & "',harga ='" & TextBox4.Text & "' where kode_barang = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
 simpan.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: but that command doesn't work with this `simpan.CommandText = "update jadwal set waktu_booking = '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "', status_booking = " & TextBox4.Text & " where id_penyewa = '" & TextBox3.Text & "'"
        simpan.ExecuteNonQuery()` i am not getting where i go wrong.. the error is "invalid column name 'OK'.. it mean textbox4.text @Al-3sli

Comment: i've edited my comment before.. sorry late :) @Al-3sli

Comment: Just add '' for textbox4 like this `'" & TextBox4.Text & "'`

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple issues with this...

- Your Syntax is wrong on your update statement (Al-3sli beat me to that one).
- Your textbox values will cause issues if a user types a single quote in the text box (For Example: The word "Wasn't".

  - Add the replace function to each textbox `TextBox3.text.Replace("'","''")` That will replace single ticks with two single ticks.

You might also consider using [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)